# Suzuki exceptional characters with $\epsilon = -1$

Tags: finite-groups, characters, frobenius-groups

I have a question about Suzuki's theory of exceptional characters of finite groups. If you are familiar with this theory, then I'm just asking: can we always choose $\epsilon=1$?

If not, here is a simpler version of the question:

Suppose we have a subgroup $H \leq G$ and a set $Y$ of irreducible characters of $H$ such that whenever $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are differences of characters from $Y$, then the scalar products $(\psi_1,\psi_2)_H = (\psi_1^G,\psi_2^G)_G$ are equal.

For example, $G$ could be a Frobenius group with Frobenius complement $H$, and $Y$ could be all the irreducible characters of $H$ with a fixed degree.

If $|Y| \geq 3$, then we can prove that there is a unique sign $\epsilon \in \{ 1, -1\}$ and unique irreducible characters $\chi_i$ of $G$ so that $\phi_i^G - \phi_j^G = \epsilon( \chi_i -\chi_j)$ for all $\phi_i,\phi_j \in Y$.

(The case $|Y|=1$ is silly since $\phi_i^G-\phi_i^G=0$, and the case $|Y|=2$ loses uniqueness, because you can always switch $\chi_i$ and $\chi_j$ by flipping the sign $\epsilon$; in particular in both of these cases we can choose $\epsilon=1$.)

In other words, to each irreducible character $\phi_i$ of $H$ in $Y$, there is some irreducible character $\chi_i$ of $G$ so that we either always have $\phi_i^G - \phi_j^G = \chi_i - \chi_j$ (this is $\epsilon=1$) or we always have $\phi_i^G - \phi_j^G = \chi_j - \chi_i$ (this is $\epsilon=-1$).

In all the examples I've checked (a somewhat small number admittedly, this is a lot of setup to check), $\epsilon=1$. Does the other case actually occur?

Comment: There are no counterexamples with $H$ a Frobenius complement in $G$ with $|G|\leq 2000$. I'm not sure of another efficient source of examples. I have an algorithm to list all "sets of special classes" (or TI subsets) and to then find $Y$ from this, but for a given $H\leq G$ the number of TI subsets appears to suffer from combinatorial explosion too often.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean to say that $\epsilon$ should be the same for each pair of characters?

Comment: yes, either the phi and chi "line up" all the time, or "are reversed" all the time, no mixing. I haven't seen a proof that is convincing from reading, only from just writing it out (which is easy, except for finding a good notation before you know the $\chi_i$ and $\epsilon$ are unique). Here are some of the steps: $[(\phi_1 -\phi_2)^G,(\phi_1-\phi_3)^G]_G = 1$, so the common constituent gets labelled $\pm \chi_1$, then the difference of those two differences, $(\phi_3-\phi_2)^G$, is also a difference of two $\chi$ so the signs have to line up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G = \newcommand{\PSL}{\operatorname{PSL}}\PSL(2,8)$. Let $A$ be the non-identity elements of a Sylow 3-subgroup, and let $H=N_G(A)\cong D_{18}$ be its normalizer. Partition $\newcommand{\Irr}{\operatorname{Irr}}\Irr(H)$ into equivalence classes of those irreducible characters that agree outside of $A$. We get three equivalence classes, $\{ 1 \} \subset \hat H$, $\{-1\} \subset \hat H$, and $Y=\{ \phi_i \in \Irr(H) : \deg(\phi_i) = 2 \}$. Similarly we find a set $X=\{ \chi_i \in \Irr(G) : \deg(\chi_i) = 7 \}$ that agrees outside of the $G$-normal closure of $A$.

Since $A$ is a TI-set, Suzuki's theory (or a direct calculation) shows that induction to $G$ is an isometry from the span of the differences of characters in $Y$ onto the span of differences of characters in $X$. However, direct calculation shows that $\epsilon=-1$ here: $\phi_i^G - \phi_j^G = \chi_j - \chi_i$ for every $1 \leq i,j \leq 4$.

Here is the character table of $G$ on the left (with $H\setminus A$ pressed to the left, followed by $A$, followed by $G \setminus H$) and the induced characters in a second copy of the table on the right. You can see how clearly the $\epsilon=-1$ shows up with all the negated character values: $\chi_i(a) = - \phi_i(a) = - \phi_i^G(a)$.

[image: Character table of PSL(2,8) with induced character to the side]

It is somewhat neat that this same group also supports $\epsilon=1$ for the bottom half of the table. Here we take $\hat A$ to be the non-identity elements of a Sylow 7-subgroup, and otherwise do the obvious thing: $\hat H = N_G(\hat A) \cong D_{14}$, $\hat Y = \{ \hat\phi_i \in \Irr(\hat H) : \deg(\hat\phi_i) = 2 \}$ is the only non-trivial collection of irreducible characters of $\hat H$ agreeing outside of $\hat A$, and $\hat X = \{ \hat\chi_i \in \Irr(G) : \deg(\hat \chi_i) = 9 \}$ is the only non-trivial collection of irreducible characters of $G$ agreeing outside the normal closure of $\hat A$. Here the value of $\hat \epsilon=1$ is very clear as the characters simply agree on $\hat A$.

$\PSL(2,2^n)$ is a good group to look at because of its Suzuki nature, but actually this thing happens in $\PSL(2,q)$ for $q \in \{ 13,17,19\}$ as well. My TI-set finder is still finding all TI-sets, so is still prohibitively slow for many groups, and so I'm not sure what other sorts of groups might work. I put a [few more groups up at my homepage](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~jack/2014-02-04-SuzukiExceptional.pdf).

Comment: Awesome! $\text{PSL}(2,2^n)$ were precisely the groups I was thinking about, but I couldn't get the GAP working.  Is this true for higher $2^n$?  Also, I would be very interested in exploring whether there exist solvable (non-CA-group) examples.

Comment: I'm still working on very suzuki-y examples now (Sz(8) right now). Cleaning up the gap functions to produce the pdf above (mostly) automatically.

Comment: Almost CA examples are given: PSL(2,13), PSL(2,17), PSL(2,19) have dihedral Sylow 2, so are definitely not CA since the centralizer of a central involution is not abelian, but actually every other non-identity element has an abelian centralizer.

Comment: I meant that solvable examples would probably be non-CA since nonabelian solvable CAs are Frobenius, which I recall you didn't have much luck with, but nonetheless it is certainly interesting to see non-solvable non-CA examples.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see the solvable part. I haven't done much exhaustive checking. The number of TI-sets can be very large in a single group, then each TI set creates multiple sets Y, blah blah. I think I checked non-nilpotents up to 30 :-) and I don't remember if nilpotents were valid to ignore, or just too much of a pain. In the CA-ish world, H is usually the normalizer of a Hall subgroup.

Comment: Looks like $\epsilon=-1$ is reasonably common. There is something strange going on with rectangular blocks of exceptional characters and classes. G=PSU(3,5) and H=A a Sylow 5-subgroup has 3 characters and 4 classes (of non-identity elements). However on the central class, the character values differ for chi and phi, so I think maybe that class is supposed to be ignored, but I'm not sure why.